JavaScript Extension Not Triggering in Odoo 16 Tree View
I am working on an Odoo 16 module for insurance management and have encountered an issue with a JavaScript extension that is not being triggered as expected. My goal is for users to be redirected to a detailed view of an insurance claim when any field in a tree view within the insurance.details view is clicked, but the script doesn't appear to be called at all.
When a row in this tree view within the insurance.details view is clicked, I expect the JavaScript method _onRowClicked to be triggered. If the model is "insurance.details", it should then open the claim.details form. However, the script does not seem to be executed at all when clicking on fields; the console log "Script called" never appears in the browser's console. Clicking on the button "View Details" correctly triggers a transition to the claim.details form, but this is not the overall behavior I want, as I need the entire row to be clickable.
manifest.py:
{
    'name': 'Insurance Management',
    'version': '16.0.1.1.1',
    'summary': """Insurance Management & Operations""",
    'description': """Insurance Management""",
    'author': 'Cybrosys Techno Solutions',
    'company': 'Cybrosys Techno Solutions',
    'website': 'https://www.cybrosys.com',
    'category': 'Industries',
    'depends': ['account', 'base', 'crm', 'web'],
    'license': 'AGPL-3',
    'data': [
        'security/ir.model.access.csv',
        'data/insurance_management_data.xml',
        'views/claim_details_views.xml',
        'views/employee_details_views.xml',
        'views/insurance_details_views.xml',
        'views/policy_details_views.xml',
        'views/insurance_management_menus.xml',
        'views/crm_lead_views.xml'
    ],
    'images': ['static/description/banner.png'],
    'installable': True,
    'application': True,
    'auto_install': False,
    'assets': {
        'web.assets_backend': [
            '/insurance_management_cybro/static/src/css/styles.css',
            '/insurance_management_cybro/static/src/js/list_controller.js'
        ]
    },
}


list_controller.js
odoo.define("insurance_management_cybro.list_controller", function (require) {
  "use strict";

  console.log("Script called");

  var ListController = require("web.ListController");

  ListController.include({
    _onRowClicked: function (event) {
      console.log("Row clicked", event);
      if (this.modelName === "insurance.details") {
        var action = {
          type: "ir.actions.act_window",
          view_type: "form",
          view_mode: "form",
          res_model: "claim.details",
          views: [[false, "form"]],
          target: "current",
          res_id: event.data.id,
        };
        return this.do_action(action);
      }

      this._super.apply(this, arguments);
    },
  });
});


insurance_details_views.xml
<page string="Claims">
    <field name="claim_ids" id="add_claim" context="{'default_policy_number': policy_number, 'default_force_readonly': True}">
        <tree create="true" delete="false" class="claims-in-insurance">
        <button name="open_claim_action" string="View Details" type="object" class="oe_highlight"/>
            <field name="external_claim_number" optional="show"/>
            <field name="date_claimed" optional="show"/>
            <field name="claim_status" optional="show"/>
            <field name="cause_of_claim" optional="show" />
            <field name="detailed_cause" optional="show" />
            <field name="total_claim_amount" optional="show" />
        </tree>
    </field>
</page>

Any insights or suggestions would be highly appreciated!

Replace your list_controller.js with the following list_renderer.js.
/** @odoo-module **/

import { ListRenderer } from "@web/views/list/list_renderer";
import { patch } from "@web/core/utils/patch";

patch(ListRenderer.prototype, 'insurance_management.renderer', {

    focusCell(column, forward = true) {
        console.log('RowClicked')
        this._super(column, forward);
    }

})

You can use focusCell or any other function that is called upon the click of a row in a list, as this function is called upon each time a row is clicked.
Secondly, FIx your manifest as given below; the previous version had / before it, which prevented the script file from loading correctly.
'assets': {
    'web.assets_backend': [
        'insurance_management_cybro/static/src/js/list_renderer.js'
    ]
},

